# php and nginx on virtual private server configuration problem - ip works but not domain

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I have a VPS setup that isn't working properly.

Environment: Ubuntu 18.04, php7.4, postgresql and nginx

The IP address for the server resolves successfully and shows default "Success" page served. The domain I want to use to point to the server does not work, however, and resolves 404. I feel like this is a simple fix but after a day of searching I haven't found it yet.

Help is appreciated!

Troubleshooting:

nslookup on windows resolves domain name to the correct IP address (I can ssh into server with just domain name)

the domain still remains not found when using the domain in my browser. Here is the /etc/nginx/sites-available/temp.domain:

```
    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name temp.domain;

        root /var/www/temp.domain/public_html;

        index index.php index.html;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/temp.domain.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/temp.domain.error.log;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/var/run/php-fpm.socket;

            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
```

default config:

```
    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
     root /var/www/html;

            # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
            index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

            server_name 192.169.0.1; #temp ip address

            location / {
                    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }

            # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
            #
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            #
            #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
            #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            }

            # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
            # concurs with nginx's one
            #
            location ~ /\.ht {
                    deny all;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have two `server` blocks? Also, `server_name 192.169.0.1;` doesn't look right as an IP address is not a name.

Comment: So put everything in one server block? and I masked the ip address.

Comment: Yes, try with only one server block and the correct `server_name`. This block will also be used even when accessing via IP.

Answer (score 0):

had to install php-config and then make sure php.ini has postgresql extensions enabled. Also had to fix the server block in nginx sites-available/default